# Creating a Subject

Tags: java, rx-java, subject, reactivex, subject-observer

I'm implementing a byte message deserializer, which would dispatch deserialized messages on a dispatcher interface and return an observable of all `Throwable`s thrown, so that client code can handle the errors.

A sketch of the prototype of the method doing that:

```
Observable<Throwable> dispatchDeserializedMessages(Observable<byte[]>, Dispatcher)
```

Now as of recent I am familiar with `Subject<T, R>`, which would fit here perfectly, e.g.

```
Subject<byte[], Throwable> dispatchDeserializedMessages(Dispatcher)
```

But there are no convenience methods like `create()` which could easily delegate to an observer and an observable. All concrete implementations unify `T` with `R`, so there's no way I could use one of those.

So my concrete question: Is there a way I can instantiate a suitable `Subject<byte[], Throwable>` which delegates to an `Observer` and `Observable`? Is there any other way I can create such a `Subject` without having to implement (in the sense of having to delegate each implemented method by hand) the whole of `Subject`, `Observable` and `Observer`?

Comment: Would you find an advantage in wrapping your `byte[]` in a Class, maybe named `DeserializedMessage` or such?

Comment: Not really, I'd call that a disadvantage. If I understand correctly, you propose to outsource the decoding step into a method producing `DeserializedMessage`s from `byte[]` chunks. I'd much rather stay with dual/visitor coding for now (call the `onTypeOfMessage()` on the dispatcher), because it solves the needed part (type-safe extensible tools) of the expression problem for us.

Comment: YMMV, but I just hate passing primitive types around, because invariably it seems something changes, and you've got no room to maneuver.

Comment: You might be right when facing a long-term industry project, but this is just for a homework assignment implementing an IETF RFC. The `byte[]` comes straight from the socket's `InputStream` and I doubt that will change for the next 2 months :).

Comment: Oh, homework -- yeah, the simplest, quickest-written solution is best :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching to Subject-based API might not be the best idea because you change a potentially cold API into a mandatory hot API. In your original design, the consumer of the `Throwable` sequence would assume when it subscribes, the `Observable<byte[]>` gets subscribed to too.

Otherwise, I have a [blog series](http://akarnokd.blogspot.hu/2015/06/subjects-part-1.html) about creating `Subject`s but you can't avoid the heavy lifting with them.